# Unable to automatically group dates in Excel 2010 Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have an Excel document stored on the network drive.

I have a field called "delivered" formatted as date and I'm 99% confident it's actually a date. =TYPE confirmed it as a number, used Datevalue and posted over the source to make absolutely sure.

I have placed "delivered" in my row labels. I have sorted it to confirm that it's sorting as a date. When I select the drop down for Row Labels "Date Filters" is an option that appears.

I do not have missing, blank, or error values in the source data for the field "delivered."

With all that said, when I right click on a date value in the rows and select "Group" it tells me that I cannot group the selection. And "Group Field" in the ribbon is greyed out.

I've refreshed the pivot table, I've restarted Excel, but no luck.

Help? :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a stray text value amongst the dates. To find it, sort the pivot table (not the source table) by the date column with A-Z as the sort order. Any text will be listed before the dates.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the sort (in the pivot table) sorts by date and all the individual date rows in the pivot table pass the TYPE() test. Basically, that didn't turn up any stray text values.  I'm baffled on this.  It's either something simple which I've looked over or something incredibly obscure.

Comment: Nope. Confirmed in both the pivot table and the source data.

Comment: Any chance you could share the workbook of a file that shows that behaviour? I'd run the pivot on one half of the data, then on the other half, then in increasingly smaller chunks of data, until I can identify the culprit.

Comment: Unfortunately not, due to some of the sensitivity of the information.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: well then, how about YOU divide the data into chunks and run the pivot on parts of the data only. You will be likely to find the culprit.